# Adding another column causes checkboxes to stop working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, onclick, append

At least, it *was* rendering before. I created a [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) that contains rows of documents (populated by JSON data) and a checkbox that corresponds to each. Clicking on a checkbox adds it to a separate div (a "Favorites List"), and it was working until recently.

I incorporated a few other columns into the table and for some reason it appears to have conflicted with the checkbox favoriting. I believe there's something I have to add/update to my code to go along with the new columns, but I'm not sure how I'd go about it. Any thoughts?

#### Loading table data:

```
loadTableData() {
    $.noConflict();
    let tableRes = JSONfile.d.results.filter(function(val) { 
      return (val.FileLeafRef.trim().length > 0);
    }).map(function(obj) {
      return {
        "Path": obj.EncodedAbsUrl,
        "Titles": obj.File.Name,
        "Categories": obj.ResourceType.results.map(function(val) {
          return val.Label;
        }).join(";"),
        "Blank": ''
        }
      });
```

#### Rendering DataTable:

```
$('#km-table-id').DataTable( {
      columns: [
        { data: "Blank" },
        { data: "Titles" }, // populates col-2 column with docs
        { data: "Categories" }, // hidden col-3 categories
        { data: "Blank" }
      ],
      columnDefs: [
        {
          data: "Path",
          ordering:  true, targets: [1],
          render: function(data, type, row) {
            return $('<a>')
              .attr({target: "_blank", href: row.Path})
              .text(data)
              .wrap('<div></div>')
              .parent()
              .html();
          },
          targets: [1]
        },
        { searchable: true, targets: [2], visible: false }, 
      ],
      data: tableRes,
      language: { searchPlaceholder: "Search All Documents" },
      lengthMenu: [ 10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500 ],
      order: [],
      pageLength: 500,
    //   paging: true,
      pagingType: "full_numbers",
      responsive: true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        scrollXInner: true,
        scrollY: 550,
      sDom: '<"top">rt<"bottom"flp><"left">' // puts dropdown on bottom
    });
```

#### Favorites functionality:

```
function faveFunc(evt) {
    var anchor = $($(evt.target).prev().find("a")[0]).clone();
    switch($(".populate-faves").find("a:contains(" + $(anchor).text() + ")").length)
    {
      case 0:
        $(".populate-faves").append(anchor);
        break;
      default:
        $(".populate-faves > a:contains(" + $(anchor).text() + ")").remove();
        break;
    }

    console.log(faveFunc);

  }; // ------------ faveFunc


function newList() {
    let data = $(evt.target).prev().find("a").eq(0).html();
     let outputList = $(".populate-faves");

     $(".populate-faves").html("");

    $("#km-table-id tbody tr").each(function(i, el) {
      let fave = $(".checkbox-class", el);
      let itemText = $(data, el);

      if(fave.prop("checked")) {
        outputList.append("<li>" + itemText.html() + "<li>");
      }
    });
  };


  $(".checkbox-class").on("click", faveFunc);
  $("#add-id").on("click", function(){
    console.log($(this));
  });
```

#### HTML snippet:

```
<table id="km-table-id" class="cell-border display stripe-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Categories</th>
              <th>My Favorites</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <!-- <tbody>

          </tbody>  -->

        </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update: I found a (working) solution.

Basically the DataTable column of "Titles" has to be in the last position to properly correspond with each checkbox. I'm sure there's a solution where I can have columns come after and the checkbox appending will work, but this is okay for now.

```
$('#km-table-id').DataTable( {
      columns: [
        { data: "Blank" },
        { data: "Categories" }, // hidden
        { data: "Blank" },
        { data: "Titles" } // MUST be in last position to respond w/ checkboxes
      ],
      columnDefs: [
        {
          data: "Path", 
          ordering:  true, targets: [3],
          render: function(data, type, row) {
            return $('<a>')
              .attr({target: "_blank", href: row.Path})
              .text(data)
              .wrap('<div></div>')
              .parent()
              .html();
          },
          targets: [3]
        },
        { searchable: true, targets: [1], visible: false },
      ],
```

...

I tried to implement a cleaner version where columnDefs is nested under `{ data: "Titles"...`, but it didn't work. For the time being I'm sticking with the above code.